# DWG specification document for parsing a DWG file?

Tags: autocad

I am extending the Apache Tika parser for DWG files so that I can parse text out of DWG files.

Currently someone else has written some basic metadata parsing which is great. But the newer versions of DWG are not yet supported.

I would like to add that support, and extend what is possible to parse.

I read around online and the Spec for DWG file format is proprietary as far as I can tell, so does that mean there is no open specification document?

Any help anyone can contribute to help me parse DWG files would be appreciated!

Comment: The DXF format could be an alternate solution.

Comment: It is what proprietary means!   Sort of defeats purpose if you publish a spec on it.

Comment: @nicholas-dipiazza Did you succeed in your task of creating a parser for DWG? I need the same. Can we collaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/tika/pull/395 here u go

Answer (score 2):

While DWG files are [a proprietary binary format by Autodesk](https://www.autodesk.com/products/dwg), they gave some visibility at some point to the [Open DesignAlliance](https://www.opendesign.com/) and allowed them to make an open spec.

https://www.opendesign.com/files/guestdownloads/OpenDesign_Specification_for_.dwg_files.pdf

It's not perfect. You'll see situations where they weren't given enough information to prefect define something... such as:

> We have occasionally seen other values here but their meaning (and importance) is unclear.

But it's better than nothing!